# What is the motivation behind STDC negative definitions (for example __STDC_NO_VLA__)?

Tags: c, language-lawyer

ISO/IEC 9899:202x (E) working draft — February 5, 2020 C17..C2x N2479:

> `__STDC_NO_VLA__` The integer constant 1, intended to indicate that the implementation does not
> support variable length arrays or variably modified types.

Question: why `__STDC_NO_VLA__` and not `__STDC_VLA__` (or `__STDC_HAS_VLA__`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the negative sense allows writing new code to be compiled in both C 2011 and C 1999 implementations that will use VLAs when they are available.

Suppose we are writing for a C 2011 implementation or later but also want to be able to compile for C 1999. If the code were:

```
#if __STDC_VLA__
   … Use VLAs.
#else
   … Do not use VLAs.
#endif
```

then this code would not use VLAs when compiled with a C 1999 implementation even though that implementation supported VLAs. In contrast, if the code were:

```
#if __STDC_NO_VLA__
   … Do not use VLAs.
#else
   … Use VLAs.
#endif
```

then the code will use VLAs if and only if they are available (always in C 1999 and when not contraindicated in C 2011).

Comment: So requiring a positive check to be fully standards-compliant would break preexisting C99 code?

Comment: @AndrewHenle: No, this is not about preexisting code.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: Yes, I did. You asked whether requiring a positive check to be fully standards-compliant would break preexisting code. I answered no. And I added that this is not about preexisting code. Preexisting code that is strictly conforming to C 1999 would compile, not break, when compiled with C 2011 in a VLA-supporting implementation, regardless of whether it used VLAs or not and regardless of what sense were given to a VLA-feature-test macro…

Comment: … Preexisting code that is strictly conforming to C 1999 and that used VLAs would break when compiled with C 2011 in a non-VLA-supporting implementation. That would be true regardless of what sense were given to a VLA-feature-test macro. So preexisting code is completely irrelevant to the sense of the feature-test macro; it either breaks or does not break according to whether it uses VLA and the C 2011 implementation supports them, and the availability of a feature-test macro does not alter that regardless of sense because the preexisting code does not test the macro.

Comment: @EricPostpischil 1. Fix for C99: `#if ! defined(__STDC_VLA__) || __STDC_VLA__`. 2. Then why C11 has introduced `XXX_HAS_SUBNORM` instead of introducing `XXX_NO_SUBNORM`?

Comment: @pmor: (a) The fact there is a more complicated expression that gets the job done is not a detriment to the choice of defining the sense so that a simpler expression suffices. (b) The subnormal feature macro was not introducing a change in the standard’s requirements about subnormal support (that is, not making any change about whether it is or is not required), just providing a new test. Neither sense for that macro would enable writing code with the backwards compatibility I describe.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Also, why `__STDC_NO_THREADS__` when C99 has no support of `threads.h` header? Why not `__STDC_THREADS__` (or `__STDC_HAS_THREADS__`)?  For the moment I don't see the consistency in the logic of feature macros naming. Which confuses.

Comment: @EricPostpischil In C99 `#if FLT_HAS_SUBNORM` will be false. However, in C99 due to absence of feature macros related to subnormals support, it is assumed that subnormals are supported (same situation as with VLAs). Hence, _this code would not use support of subnormals when compiled with a C 1999 implementation even though that implementation supported subnormals_.

Comment: @pmor: Re “it is assumed that subnormals are supported”: No, it is not. The C 1999 standard did not provide that subnormal support may be assumed. It did require VLAs, it did not require subnormals, and this suffices to explain the difference in those two feature test macros.

Comment: @EricPostpischil `it did not require subnormals`: thanks, it does explain the difference. However, what about `__STDC_NO_THREADS__`? As C99 does not require subnormals, it does not require `threads.h`. Then why C11 introduces `__STDC_NO_THREADS__` instead of `__STDC_THREADS__` (or `__STDC_HAS_THREADS__`)? The same question goes for `__STDC_NO_ATOMICS__`.

Comment: This makes perfect sense. To put it another way, if they defined  `__STDC_VLA__`, the fact that this macro is **not** defined wouldn't necessarily mean that VLA's are not supported.

Answer (score 4):

Adding a **positive** preprocessor definition to indicate support for variable length arrays would break existing code.

Variable length arrays are a required feature in C99, so code that is fully standard-compliant with C99 can use variable length arrays without depending on any preprocessor definition.

Variable length arrays were made optional in C11 ([the `__STDC_NO_VLA__` macro first appeared in C11](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.10.8.3), not C17), so they may not exist and fully-standard compliant C11 or later code can not use variable length arrays without doing some sort of check. Thus it makes sense that a preprocessor definition to indicate if they're supported be created.

But C code using variable length arrays without referring to any such a definition already existed, so requiring a positive preprocessor definition to check for variable length arrays could break existing code that assumes variable length arrays exist without any check.

Comment: This answer would be correct with C11 changed to C99.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica It's a one-off-the-standard day for me, apparently.  The old F77 from college must be resurfacing...

Comment: This answer does not explain the decision. Given existing code strictly conforming to C 1999 and using variable-length arrays, compiling it with a C 2011 implementation that did not support variable-length arrays would fail regardless of whether a `VLA` macro were defined with a positive sense or a negative sense, since the existing code would have no such macro tests. To get old code that uses VLAs working with C 2011, one has to insert `#if` tests. Whether the test sense is positive or negative is then of no consequence, as the changes can be easily designed for either sense.